# Inserting files into SQL Server using vba issue

Tags: sql-server, vba

I'm trying to incorporate the following code into my existing code.

Here is my test code that works:

```
Sub test()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.recordSet
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.recordSet

con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Password=;User ID=;Initial 
Catalog='" & Worksheets("Settings").Range("C2").Value & _
        "';Data Source='" & Worksheets("Settings").Range("A2").Value & "';"

'Open database connection
rs.ActiveConnection = con

rs.Open "select * from QuoteData", con, adOpenKeyset, 
adLockOptimistic

Set mstream = New ADODB.Stream
mstream.Type = adTypeBinary
mstream.Open
mstream.LoadFromFile "c:\temp\pictures\pic1.jpg"
rs.Fields("PII_Image1").Value = mstream.Read
rs.Update
End Sub
```

This is the code I'm using in my existing code. UpdateQuery is part of a larger string. I want to integrate it with my existing update query.

```
Set mstream = New ADODB.Stream
mstream.Type = adTypeBinary
mstream.Open
mstream.LoadFromFile "c:\temp\pictures\pic1.jpg"
updateQuery = updateQuery & "PII_Image1=convert(varbinary(MAX),'mstream.Read'),"
mstream.Close
```

This code runs, but it only inserts something into the database that looks like '`0x6D73747265616D2E52656164`' which isn't correct. I'm trying to figure out why. If I take away the convert piece, it says it can't convert `varchar` to `varbinary(MAX)`.

Comment: You're saying the first section of code runs even with the stray `'` quote? Looking at the lines above it, I think there's an issue with that part of code.  Also, what are you expecting to be added to the database? A file?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something there is no stray quote, but the code I have does run and inserts into the database correctly. I'm expecting to add JPG image files and maybe pdf's eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `updateQuery = updateQuery & "PII_Image1 = 0x" & BinaryToHex(mstream.Read) & "),"`

Also, add the following function to your module:

```
'Simple binary-to-hex Function
'2003 Antonin Foller, Motobit Software
'BinaryToHex is byte-to-byte VBS function and it is suitable only for small amount of binary data - up to 100kB.
'If you want to work with bigger size, please see HexString property of Motobit's ScriptUtil.ByteArray object.

Private Function BinaryToHex(Binary)
  Dim c1, Out, OneByte

  'For each source byte
  For c1 = 1 To LenB(Binary)
    'Get the byte As hex
    OneByte = Hex(AscB(MidB(Binary, c1, 1)))

    'append zero For bytes < 0x10
    If Len(OneByte) = 1 Then OneByte = "0" & OneByte

    'join the byte To OutPut stream
    Out = Out & OneByte
  Next

  'Set OutPut value
  BinaryToHex = Out
End Function
```

Comment: That gives "Incorrect syntax near '0xd8ff'.

Using ' " & mstream.Read & " ' gets further saying "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '?????????Ea'.

Comment: Try `updateQuery = updateQuery & "PII_Image1=" & mstream.Read & ","`. This intentionally avoids the convert and single quotes, because if your underlying field is binary then you can set it directly to a binary value.

Comment: That line gives "Incorrect syntax near ','." which I can fix by adding apostrophes like `updateQuery = updateQuery & "PII_Image1='" & mstream.Read & "',"`

It then complains about not being able to convert from varchar to varbinary(max). We should be close because if I add msgbox mstream.read it does match both my working example and the in progress example.

Comment: Just to confirm, what is the SQL data type of the field "PII_Image1"?

Comment: It's varbinary(MAX).

Comment: Also, to confirm, are you removing the final comma or alternatively are you appending more fields to the SET statement, and then making sure there is no comma at the end of the SET statement?

Comment: Yes at the end of the statement the comma is removed. If I comment out this line the rest of the statement runs normally.

Comment: The reason your first approach works is because you are setting the binary field directly with a binary value. The reason the second approach doesn't work is because you are trying to put the binary value into a string and then use that string as an update command. The binary value has to be converted first. I don't know why I didn't realize that earlier. I revised my answer to include an additional function that converts the binary value to a hexidecimal string, which you can pass into your update string.

Comment: Excellent, that worked beautifully. If you'd be willing to explain how this all worked further I'd appreciate it. I'm curious how the first example converted to hex. But either way I'm thrilled. Thanks so much.